# How to add together two columns in pandas without receiving SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to add add one column to another using pandas with:

```
merged_df.loc[:, 'airline_name'] = merged_df.loc[:, 'airline_name'] + merged_df['airline_icao_unique_code']
```

but every time I try I receive the warning :

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> self.obj[selected_item_labels] = value
> Process finished with exit code 0

Is there any way to do this without triggering this warning? I have tried altering the syntax and creating temporary variables but I cant seem to get it to work. I have also tried using the `.copy()` function but still no dice.

Comment: Hi rylan, can you please demonstrate how ```airline_name``` and ```airline_icao_unique_code``` columns look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to `merged_df` being a subset of another `DataFrame`. The easiest way to fix this is to use `.copy()` before performing this operation:

```py
merged_df = merged_df.copy()
merged_df['airline_name'] = merged_df['airline_name'] + merged_df['airline_icao_unique_code']
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked, I had tried using .copy() in the statement before, nut not outside of it.

Comment: Of course! I actually had a fairly in-depth answer on this same topic that's buried in `pandas` Issue tracker if you want another reference: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17476

Answer (score 0):

```
merged_df['airline_name'] = merged_df['airline_name'] + merged_df['airline_icao_unique_code']
```

Comment: I've tried that and gotten the almost the same error

Comment: @rylan please add `merged_df.head().to_dict()` to your post